# What happened to Ropsten Faucet?

Tags: testnets, ropsten, faucets, ropsten-revival

I usually get ether for Ropsten Tesnet at http://faucet.ropsten.be:3001/, now the site seems to be offline. My question is what happened to the site, but more important, now how can I get ether for ropsten testnet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a message with your Ropsten Testnet ETH address in [The NEW If you need some Ropsten Testnet Ethers ...](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethdev/comments/72ltwj/the_new_if_you_need_some_ropsten_testnet_ethers/) and you will get ETH within a few hours.

Comment: And thanks for the ether and my request for a little more eth, it is being very useful for my tests.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the Metamask faucet at https://faucet.metamask.io, always works for me.

Comment: This does not work anymore, thought the page is there, but there's no controls available

Answer (score 2):

Non of the faucet works for me anymore

`https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmVAwVKys271P5EQyEfVSxm7BJDKWt42A2gHvNmxLjZMps/`

[image]

`https://faucet.metamask.io`

[image]

`https://faucet.ropsten.be/` will say that transaction is sent, but there's no provided hash

Comment: This might be related to http://cryptovest.com/news/ethereums-ropsten-testnet-still-forked

Answer (score 2):

faucet.ropsten.be has reached its end of life.

Answer (score 1):

The new faucet I found is Kyber Network's faucet https://faucet.kyber.network/

Answer (score 0):

Here's another faucet:
https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmVAwVKys271P5EQyEfVSxm7BJDKWt42A2gHvNmxLjZMps/

More info about it here:
https://blog.b9lab.com/when-we-first-built-our-faucet-we-deployed-it-on-the-morden-testnet-70bfbf4e317e

Answer (score 0):

Also had some issues here, but this one seems to work => https://faucet.dimensions.network/